# how to configure while loop to run while a non-zero value is in a list

Tags: python

I was wondering if I have a list of ints like so `[1,3,2,0,1]`, which I look to decrement within a while loop until the list reaches a state of `[0,0,0,0,0]`, I was wondering how to build the condition for the while loop. Thank you!

EDIT: I'm not trying to simply decrement the items in the list in a straightforward way, but i have something like this:

```
some_list = [1,3,2,0,1]
for i in range(len(some_list)):
  processed_list = process_list(some_list)
  for item in processed_list:
    if item != 0:
      break
```

I was hoping to rewrite this to have the non-zero check be written without a break.

Comment: It is better to use for loops or **list comprehensions** instead.

Comment: `while any(some_list):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
l=[1,3,2,0,1]
check=0
while True:
    if all(x==0 for x in l):
        break
    else:
        if l[check]==0:
            pass
        elif l[check]-1==0:
            l[check]=l[check]-1
            check+=1
        else:
            l[check]=l[check]-1
print(l)
```